# Is it acceptable to add a "using namespace" immediately after the namespace declaration?

Tags: namespaces, c++-cli, typedef, using-statement

I have a small namespace containing some type definitions, which I use to make my code look cleaner. However I don't want to have to add a "using namespace ..." line to every file that uses one of these types, after all I already have to add a #include for the file.

---

*MyFile.cpp:*

```
#include "typedefs.h"
void Bob()
{
    IntList^ list = gcnew IntList;
}
```

---

*typedefs.h:*

```
namespace Typedefs
{
    typedef List<int> IntList;
    typedef array<int> IntArray;
    typedef List<Byte> ByteList;
    typedef array<Byte> ByteArray;
    typedef List<String^> StringList;
    typedef array<String^> StringArray;
}
using namespace Typedefs;
```

---

Would it be acceptable to add the "using namespace" line immediately after the namespace declaration? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an unnamed namespace. If you want to have the names visible only to the files in which you have included the headers

```
namespace {
  int i = 10;
}
```

above has the same effect as like below code

```
namespace randomName {
  int i = 10;
}
using randomName;
```

so nothing will be accessible from any other file.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into your answer and found it reiterated in http://winterdom.com/dev/cpp/nspaces.html

Answer (score 3):

It's possible but I don't think it's wise. It just defeats the whole purpose of the namespace by exposing its contents everywhere. If you want the comfort of not having to specify `Typedefs::` or `using Typedefs::xxx;` or `using namespace Typedefs;` I'd just not create a namespace at all.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a 'using namespace XXX;' directive into a header file is usually considered to be a bad idea, as it does defeat the idea of having a namespace in the first place. It can easily lead to the sort of naming conflicts that the introduction of a namespace is supposed to avoid.

My advice - don't do it, if necessary stick them into the appropriate source files (.cpp) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well define your new types outside any namespace, or am I missing something?